# Get full name of network interface C#

Tags: c#, networking, command-line

I'm trying to find the network interface name from ipconfig /all. So for example if the ipconfig /all output is:

```
Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Npcap Loopback Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 01-00-4C-5F-5F-50
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.183.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I want to print "Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter". This is what I've tried:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in interfaces)
{
     richTextBox1.AppendText(adapter.Name);
}
```

But it only prints "Ethernet" instead of the full thing.

Comment: See pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetServerGetInfo

Comment: Did you try `richTextBox1.AppendText($"{adapter.Name} {adapter.Description}");`?

Comment: This is better than last suggestion : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetAdaptersInfo.html

Comment: @jdweng Nope, neither of those are helpful

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ the description is different from the name

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of ipconfig, I think the text you are seeing is made up of two things:

1. The `NetworkInterfaceType` property converted into standard strings
2. The `Name` property.

So you really just need a function to convert the enum into a string, for example it could be as simple as this:

```
private string GetNetworkTypeName(NetworkInterfaceType type) =>
    type switch
    {
        NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet => "Ethernet adapter",
        NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 => "Wireless LAN adapter",
        //etc etc...
        _ => "Other"
    };
```

And construct the name like this:

```
var interfaceName = $"{GetNetworkTypeName(adapter.NetworkInterfaceType)} {adapter.Name}";
```

Comment: This won't work for me because my computer has multiple ethernet connections. Also I need this to work on any computer.